How does one denote the vector of Gaussian Integers?
When dealing with a vector of $n$ elements where all elements are integers , it is possible to write the shorthand $u \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ to denote that vector.
I also know that $\mathbb{Z}[i] = [ a, b \in \mathbb{Z} : a + bi ]$.
Does this mean that the vector whose elements are restricted to the Gaussian Integers may be written using $u \in \mathbb{Z}^n[i]$?

I think that notation will confuse the audience.
While the notation $$u \in \mathbb{Z}^n$$ denotes the vector without confusion , the notation $$u \in \mathbb{Z}^n[i]$$ might be either $$u \in [\mathbb{Z}^n][i]$$ or $$u \in [\mathbb{Z}[i]]^n$$ making it confusing.
Maybe here one is currently meaningful , while one is currently meaningless , though there are cases where both could have validity , hence we should try to make things clear to the audience.
Let $u \in U$ , with $u=(u_1,\cdots,u_n)$ where $u_i \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ :
Here , $u$ is a vector with $n$ elements from $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ , while $U$ is the Set of all such vectors: No confusion.
Alternately , you can use what you wrote , though you have to explain to the audience what it indicates.

That makes perfect sense. Thank you so much!

The $n$ in the exponent isn't meaningless; it's literally the $n$-fold Cartesian product.
The set of ordered triples of real numbers is $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{R}^3$.
So what you're looking for an an ordered $n$-tuple of elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$; that's $\mathbb{Z}[i]^n$, or $(\mathbb{Z}[i])^n$ if you want to be clear.
